# getting nokogiri gem error trying to connect to rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to run the server so i can check my site on localhost:3000

im getting an error that something is wrong with my nokogiri gem, this is my terminal:

```
C:\sites\Moovit>rails server
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': 127: The specified procedure could
 not be found.   - Init_nokogiri (LoadError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4-x86-mingw32/
lib/nokogiri/1.9/nokogiri.so
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.
0/lib/mechanize.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/sites/Moovit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\sites\Moovit>sudo gem update -system
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\sites\Moovit>gem update -system
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update

C:\sites\Moovit>rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': 127: The specified procedure could
 not be found.   - Init_nokogiri (LoadError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4-x86-mingw32/
lib/nokogiri/1.9/nokogiri.so
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.
0/lib/mechanize.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/sites/Moovit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

C:\sites\Moovit>nokogiri -v
# Nokogiri (1.6.1)
    ---
    warnings: []
    nokogiri: 1.6.1
    ruby:
      version: 1.9.3
      platform: i386-mingw32
      description: ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
      engine: ruby
    libxml:
      binding: extension
      source: system
      compiled: 2.8.0
      loaded: 2.8.0

C:\sites\Moovit> yum install libxml libxml-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\sites\Moovit>install libxml libxml-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
install: target `libxslt-devel' is not a directory

C:\sites\Moovit>install libxml
install: missing destination file operand after `libxml'
Try `install --help' for more information.

C:\sites\Moovit>gem install nokogiri
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.1-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.6.1-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for nokogiri-1.6.1-x86-mingw32...

C:\sites\Moovit>Rails s
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/act
ive_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': 127: The specified procedure could
 not be found.   - Init_nokogiri (LoadError)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4-x86-mingw32/
lib/nokogiri/1.9/nokogiri.so
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.4.4
-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-1.0.
0/lib/mechanize.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/sites/Moovit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.6
/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

please help me find the solution, what should i do to make the server run?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Github issue,](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/375) this was a known problem with the 1.4.4 release, and was fixed in 1.4.4.1.

Looking at the console trace you posted above, I see that you ended up installing a more recent version of nokogiri (1.6.1), but there's probably some gem in your Gemfile that's specifically looking for version 1.4.4, so it's not finding the more recent version. I'd suggest manually deleting the old version (`gem uninstall nokogiri --version=1.4.4`) and then seeing if 1.6.1 will work.

One caveat: you're using an old version of Rails and possibly some older gems along with it. It's possible that whatever is looking for nokogiri 1.4.4 won't work with 1.6.1, but it's worth a try. If you still have problems, please update the question with your Gemfile and we can work from there.